# Once you have used LASSO to generate regression coefficients, is there another step that gives you information about the model?

Tags: regression, lasso, importance

I've run a LASSO to build a model out of ~60 potential predictors. I'm wondering what the next step is? If there were OLS regression I would find model fit statistics like R2 or AIC. I would also find some statistic like squared semi-partial correlation for each of the predictors.

I'm wondering if there is anything one can do for a LASSO model that tells you about its prediction accuracy, and the relative importance of the coefficients it has generated?

Comment: Is this linear regression or logistic?

Comment: What is your preferred programming language or statistics  software?

Comment: @ChristopherJohn Linear

Comment: @JanesPhillips R

Answer (score 0):

You can do repeated cross validation and if it is logistic get the ROC-AUC or perhaps the Brier score. If it is linear regression you can use R^2.

For variable importance you can use the coefficient size.

Comment: Variable importance can only be assessed by coefficient size if the design matrix was scaled columnwise to mean 0 and unit variance. I'd rather use stability selection for variable importance with LASSO, though.

Comment: @Edgar Can you elaborate on both of these ideas?

Comment: Why would you rather use stability selection out of interest? Glmnet should z-score normalise the features by default.

Comment: @ChristopherJohn yes, glmnet normalizes under the hood, but it gives back the coefficients on the original scale.

Comment: Does this mean I should be doing zscore normalisation beforehand to interpret the coefficients? Or how else to do this? Stability selection seems a bit unnecessary if coefficients give importance.

Comment: @ChristopherJohn yes, if you use glmnet, to interpret the coefficients as importance, you need to do the zscore normalization before giving the data to the glmnet-function